# How can I set a proxy for firefox using Selenium webdriver with Java?

Tags: java, selenium

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
while (true) {
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "E:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver;
String PROXY = "83.209.94.87:35923";
  //Bellow given syntaxes will set browser proxy settings using DesiredCapabilities.
  Proxy proxy = new Proxy();
  proxy.setAutodetect(false);
  proxy.setProxyType(Proxy.ProxyType.MANUAL);
  proxy.setSocksProxy(PROXY);
  DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
  cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, proxy);
  //Use Capabilities when launch browser driver Instance.
  driver = new FirefoxDriver(cap);`
```

When I run this code and firefox is launched, the proxy setting is set to 'Use system proxy settings'. How can I make it so when firefox is launched, it's proxy setting is automatically changed to the proxy I specified.

Comment: What is firefox version?

Comment: It is Version 54.0.1

Comment: @Kapil Unfortunately, it seems my questions from before were removed. I will post them again.     `GeckoDriverService service =new GeckoDriverService.Builder(firefoxBinary)` When I type this, eclipse says 'Builder' is deprecated and firefoxBinary can't be resolved to a variable. 
    `usingDriverExecutable(new File("E:\\geckodriver-v0.18.0-win64\\geckodriver.exe"))` When I type this, an error occurs saying an error occurs saying Multiple markers at this line

Comment: - The method usingDriverExecutable(java.io.File) in the type DriverService.Builder<GeckoDriverService,GeckoDriverService.‌​Builder> is not applicable for the arguments (com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File).This is continued from last comment

Comment: Also, when I type     `driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, cap, cap);` an error occurs saying Multiple markers at this line - driver cannot be resolved to a variable - The constructor FirefoxDriver(GeckoDriverService, DesiredCapabilities, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined

Comment: Lastly, the code you entered above doesn't seem to give an option socks proxies. Is it possible to set these as well through Java? Can I just type json.addProperty("socksProxy", PROXY)

Comment: I am not sure about the issues. Lets see if someone else can help you.